# Regex to validate proxy uri in python

Tags: regex, validation, proxy

I have tried a regex to validate below valid and invalid proxy URI. I need help in proofing the valid and invalid scenarios in python.

The input should be in this way:

```
000.0000.00.00                               #invalid
912.456.123.123                               #invalid
999.999.999.999:99999                         #invalid
192.168.1.1                                   #valid
192.168.1.1.1                                 #invalid
proxy.company.com:3128                        #valid
https://proxy.company.com:3128                #valid
https://proxy.company.com:3128/?action=list   #valid
user:pass@proxy.company.com:3128              #valid
localhost:8000                                #valid
http://localhost:8000                         #valid
3...3                                         #invalid
```

My regex:

```
(^(\w+)(?::)+((\w+))@)|(^https?:\/\/)|(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])|(?:\.[^0-9])|(localhost)(?::(?![7-9]\d\d\d\d)(?!6[6-9]\d\d\d)(?!65[6-9]\d\d)(?!655[4-9]\d)(?!6553[6-9])(?!0+)(?P<Port>\d{1,5}))?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$
```

These case is coming valid:

```
3...3
192.168.1.1.1
```

I need help in full proofing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your example data, one solution could be to either match an ip number, or match a url like structure or match  the structure using an `@`

```
^(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(?:https?://)?(?![\d.]+:)\w+(?:\.\w+)*:\d+\S+|\w+:\w+@(?![\d.]+:)\w+(?:\.\w+)*:\d+)$
```

In large parts (you can adjust them accordingly)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` Pattern to [match an ip number](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:https?://)?(?![\d.]+:)\w+(?:\.\w+)*:\d+\S+` Match a url like pattern which can not consists of only digits and dots before the colon
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+:\w+@(?![\d.]+:)\w+(?:\.\w+)*:\d+` Match a pattern for the username and password followed by an `@`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ga7pdJ/1)

**Note** that this pattern does not guarantee full proofing as your examples contain a wide variety of possible variations.

Comment: The fourth bird, thank you for the input. This is working for me.

Comment: This is unusual. It is giving me error for valid scenarios. For Example, these are not parsing.
`10.115.27.54:3128
user:pass@10.115.27.54:3128
user:pass@https://10.115.27.54:3128
proxy.company.com
user:pass@http://10.115.27.54:3128`

Comment: @PranayBankar That is because these are different formats than the ones that were listed in the example data.

Comment: @PranayBankar Well, there could be edge cases, but you could try it like this https://regex101.com/r/WHXVov/1

Comment: I have tried this one. `^(?:(\w+)(?::)+((\w+))@)?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|localhost|(?:https?://)?(?![\d.]+:)\w+(?:\.\w+)*:\d+\S+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?::(?![7-9]\d\d\d\d)(?!6[6-9]\d\d\d)(?!65[6-9]\d\d)(?!655[4-9]\d)(?!6553[6-9])(?!0+)(?P<Port>\d{1,5}))?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$`

Comment: @PranayBankar Very nice! A few side notes, if you use another delimiter than `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash `\/`. This part `(?::)+` is the same as `:+` which matches 1+ times a colon. This part `\d\d\d\d` you could shorten to `\d{4}` (In this example https://regex101.com/r/1QTEnE/1 it does not seem to match `proxy.company.com`)

Comment: I'm getting this message for vote.

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.